# Weird behaviour of asynchronous logging from a web page using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I am trying to track every visit on my website on the basis of cookies. I am facing a weird problem of sequence while logging of users data using AJAX.

E.g. I have 4 pages named a,b,c,d and my landing page is C where website users always land and then they navigate to other pages like a or b or d. So if an user lands on C then I send an ajax request to save his data(OS,URL,Referral,Datetime), then he goes to page a after that b ,then d 
then I got the logs in my database in following sequence:

```
URL    Visit Time
b          10:30:23
a          10:30:25
c          10:30:30
```

(it should be logged first as I fire this request first in line being a landing page).

Every page have same code to track the data and send request.

Below is my code:

```
  function getCookies(cname)
    {
    var u_id="";
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    var index_position = c.indexOf(name);
    if(index_position != -1)
    {
    var res = c.split("=");
    var u_id=res[1];
    }
    }
    return u_id;
    }
    function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) 
    {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + "; " + expires;
    }
    var os=navigator.userAgent;
    var url = window.location.href;
    var url=url.replace(/&/g, "||");
    var referral = document.referrer;
    var referral=referral.replace(/&/g, "||");
    var cookies=getCookies("tls_unique_id");
    var uniqueID=cookies;
    if(cookies=='')
    {
    var uniqueID='T_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9);
    setCookie("tls_unique_id",uniqueID,730);
    }
    php_url="http://localhost/tracking_system/sessionDataHandler2.php?os="+os+"&uniqueID="+uniqueID+"&url="+url+"&referral="+referral;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
    {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) 
    {   
    alert(xhttp.response);
    }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", php_url, true);
    xhttp.send();
```

I will really appreciate if someone can point out a problem in my code or help me with a work around.

Comment: what is the location of the script, inside <head> or <body> ?   And Did the other web pages(a,b or d) are loaded using AJAX or server request ?

Comment: Script location is <head>, and other pages are loading using simple server request (no use of ajax to load the page)